# Positioning mouse cursor on another Application's List item entry based on its text value

Tags: windows, vba, automation

I want to do an automation using Excel VBA. First of all I am not sure if its possible so I need to explain the problem first.

I would launch an application which has a list of reports , that one can run by right clicking on any of these and selecting an entry from the popup menu caled say "Run this report". The problem is the report names are displayed in a listbox.

There are so many entries I only need to run a few of them based on their names.

To achieve this I thought about placing the mouse cursor on the text displaying the appropriate report name and then trigger the right click event. These can be done using Windows APIs.

The challenge I am facing is how to hover my mouse on any particular list item based on its display text.

I can enumerate all the windows controls based on the handle of the application's window, but is it possible to get the location of any item on the screen based on the text displayed on list item.